# Using devise_token_auth and omniauth-twitter, I can not login with Twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

Sending GET request to `/auth/twitter`, I successfully authenticate with Twitter and redirect to `/auth/twitter/callback`.
But, sending GET request to `/api/current_user`, api server always return `null`. And, `user_signed_in?` always return `false`
I can not know how to sign in with Twitter. I want to get `current_user`
How do I sign in with Twitter?
* **Version**: 
Rails (API mode) 5.1.6
ruby 2.4.0
routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', controllers: {
    omniauth_callbacks: "overrides/omniauth_callbacks",
  }
  namespace :api, format: 'json' do
    root 'posts#index'
    get 'current_user', to: 'users#current'
  end
end
```

omniauth_callbacks.rb

```
module Overrides
  class OmniauthCallbacksController < DeviseTokenAuth::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def assign_provider_attrs(user, auth_hash)
    all_attrs = auth_hash["info"].slice(*user.attributes.keys)
    orig_val = ActionController::Parameters.permit_all_parameters
    ActionController::Parameters.permit_all_parameters = true
    permitted_attrs = ActionController::Parameters.new(all_attrs)
    permitted_attrs.permit({})
    user.assign_attributes(permitted_attrs)
    ActionController::Parameters.permit_all_parameters = orig_val
    user
  end
  end
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class Api::UsersController < ActionController::API
  def current
    render json: current_user
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you.But, I could not find access-token, client ,uid. redirecting to /auth/twitter/callback, api server did not return return response header including the paramaters. Please tell me about that

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following solution and modify it as you want

In your **omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb** should be the following code:

```
def callback
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])

    if @user.persisted?
      #your code here to set current_user if necessary
    else
      #your code here
    end
end

def twitter
    callback
end
```

In your **user.rb** should be the following code:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(email: auth.info['email'], /add the attributes you want to check/).first_or_create do |user|
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      #user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
      #user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
    end
end
```

Source: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Comment: Thank you.But, I could not find  access-token, client ,uid.
redirecting to /`auth/twitter/callback`, api server did not return return response header including the paramaters.
Please tell me about that

Comment: Do you have "twitter" method in your OmniauthCallbacksController?

Comment: there are not twitter method  my OmniauthCallbacksController

Comment: I changed the answer please check it out

Comment: Not Devise but Devise_token_auth

Comment: yes, I does not it works., api server did not return return response header including the paramaters.

Comment: are you testing your app in a web server? because some apis just accept https requests